# How to add intarray extension to PostgreSQL on Heroku

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, heroku

The app I have is using `intarray` extension of the PostgreSQL.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be available according to the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-extensions-postgis-full-text-search) and the command line:

```
> echo 'show extwlist.extensions' | heroku pg:psql
                                                                                extwlist.extensions                                                                                 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 btree_gist,chkpass,cube,dblink,dict_int,dict_xsyn,earthdistance,fuzzystrmatch,hstore,isn,ltree,pg_trgm,pgcrypto,pgrowlocks,pgstattuple,plpgsql,unaccent,uuid-ossp,citext,tablefunc
(1 row)
```

Also:

```
> heroku pg:psql
psql (9.1.5, server 9.1.6)
SSL connection
Type "help" for help.

=> CREATE EXTENSION intarray;
WARNING:  extension "intarray" is not whitelisted
CREATE EXTENSION
```

So does it mean I **can't use Heroku** or there IS a way to add `intarray` extension (using `idx` function for example).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have to answer my own question just to provide a little bit more details.

The `intarray` was used for extracting path information from columns containing strings like `123/312/56/9863`. That was stored (poorly) as string instead of an array in the first place.

The reason we needed `intarray` is because we it had the `idx` function.

What was happening is this:

- convert string to an array
- find the given number using the `idx`
- return the next number in sequence.

All that was done as a temporary measure. But since heroku couldn't support `idx` the only way to use it was by adding a [custom function](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Index).
But instead we converted the queries and data structure to to use `ltree` and its `index` function.

Apart from not needing a dependency on `idx` (but introducing another dependency on `ltree`), we also improved the performance of the queries by a factor of x200.

Answer (score 5):

The general consensus from the Postgres community I got was that `intarray` is obsoleted by just using `int[]` and that it's only kept around for backwards compatibility for very old applications. That's why we haven't added support for it.

So far everyone who asked for it was actually happier with `int[]` and just hadn't found it. Is there some usecase where you actually want an `intarray` column instead? We can just turn it on.

Comment: We use the `idx` function from the `intarray` which unfortunately isn't available in standard PG (unless there's a similar function of course).  Also it doesn't look like the `intarray` is actually deprecated/obsolete. Nothing is mentioned in the docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/intarray.html

Comment: @DmytriiNagirniak I think this function would provide idx for arrays of arbitrary datatypes: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Array_Index

Comment: @GregB thanks. That is certainly an option. But the function is already available and well tested through the `intarray` extension. Ideally, I'd want to stick to that instead of reinventing the wheel. But if there is no way to bring `intarray` into heroku then it will be only option for us.

Answer (score 4):

`intarray` has been whitelisted on Heroku [since March 2014](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/435), so you should be able to enable the extension directly. If you provisioned your database before that you will first need to [upgrade your database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases).

Answer (score 0):

Note: it seems that at some point Heroku stopped allowing `intarray` to be installed in the `public` schema, instead requiring it to be in the `heroku_ext` schema.  This means that if you `pull` a database from a Heroku instance that had `intarray` installed on `public` before the change, it won't work properly when you `push` it to a new instance.

You'll need to change your schema / dump to put the extension in `heroku_ext` instead (or change the schema it's installed to in your source instance before `pull`ing it).